# CSS positioning absolute requires relative position for sibling element

Tags: css, css-position

I have a simple set up where I have a hamburger style menu that enables an off canvas menu ([something like this](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/off-canvas-menu-animated-links)) that slides the main content to the right.

```
<div class="layout-wrapper" >
    <div class="layout-menu"></div>

    <header class="layout-header"></header>

    <div class="layout-content"></div>
</div>
```

So I have a container div: `layout-wrapper`.

I have the menu: `layout-menu`, with absolute positioning so that I can put the main content on top of it.

I have the header: `layout-header`, with fixed positioning so that it always will remain on top when I scroll the content

I have the content: `layout-content`.

My problem is that the `layout-content` is not visible unless i add `position: relative` to it. Why do I have to do that? Have I done a stupid mistake?

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HxFSbKqYHuPSLyELXvkY?p=preview) showing the problem. Enable the commented line in the CSS to see what it *should* look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.layout-menu` is a positioned element:

```css
.layout-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
```

But `.layout-content` is not:

```css
.layout-content {
    position: static; /* default value */
}
```

According to [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/CR-CSS21-20070719/visuren.html#z-index),

> Each box belongs to one stacking context. Each box in a given stacking
>   context has an integer stack level, which is its position on the
>   z-axis relative to other boxes in the same stacking context. Boxes
>   with greater stack levels are always formatted in front of boxes with
>   lower stack levels. [...]
>
> Each stacking context consists of the following stacking levels (from
>   back to front):
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking
>      context.
> 2. the stacking contexts of descendants with negative stack levels.
> 3. a stacking level containing in-flow non-inline-level descendants.
> 4. a stacking level for floats and their contents.
> 5. a stacking level for in-flow inline-level descendants.
> 6. a stacking level for positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto', and any descendant stacking contexts with 'z-index: 0'.
> 7. the stacking contexts of descendants with positive stack levels.

That means that `.layout-menu`, which falls in the stacking level 6, will be displayed in front of `.layout-content`, which falls in the stacking level 3.

However, if you use

```css
.layout-content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Now `.layout-content` will fall in the stacking level 6 too.

Then,

> Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.

Therefore, since `.layout-content` comes after `.layout-menu` in the document tree, `.layout-content` will be displayed in front of `.layout-menu`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because an element needs to have a `position` property other than `static` (*which is the default*) for the `z-index` property to work. This means it will not only work with `position: relative`. it will also work with `position: absolute` and `position: fixed`.

**[Give this a read to understand z-index better](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's not a mistake, you have to set `position: relative` for the `layout-content` so it can overlap `layout-menu`.

In your Off Canvas Menu example the content has also a `position: relative`.